# How to keep the same color order for multiple pie plots?

Tags: python, plotly

I am going through multiple columns and creating plotly pie charts, to check the distribution of these variables between two types of customer: `power user` and `not power user`. However the color order changes every time.

In one plot, `Yes` will be orange and `No` will , in the next plot, `Yes` will be blue and `No` will be orange.

You can see an example here, if you check the legend between the two charts:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code I am using. After some googling I tried adding `sort=False` to `go.pie` but it didn't change anything:

```
    def plot_pie(column) :

        trace1 = go.Pie(values  = churn[column].value_counts().values.tolist(),
                        labels  = churn[column].value_counts().keys().tolist(),
                        hoverinfo = "label+percent+name",
                        domain  = dict(x = [0,.48]),
                        name    = f"{target}",
                        marker  = dict(line = dict(width = 2,
                                                   color = "rgb(243,243,243)")
                                      ),
                        hole    = .6,
                        sort=False
                       )
        trace2 = go.Pie(values  = not_churn[column].value_counts().values.tolist(),
                        labels  = not_churn[column].value_counts().keys().tolist(),
                        hoverinfo = "label+percent+name",
                        marker  = dict(line = dict(width = 2,
                                                   color = "rgb(243,243,243)")
                                      ),
                        domain  = dict(x = [.52,1]),
                        hole    = .6,
                        name    = f"Not {target}" ,
                        sort=False
                       )


        layout = go.Layout(dict(title = column + f" distribution in {target} ",
                                plot_bgcolor  = "rgb(243,243,243)",
                                paper_bgcolor = "rgb(243,243,243)",
                                annotations = [dict(text = f"{target}",
                                                    font = dict(size = 13),
                                                    showarrow = False,
                                                    x = .15, y = .5),
                                               dict(text = f"not {target}",
                                                    font = dict(size = 13),
                                                    showarrow = False,
                                                    x = .88,y = .5
                                                   )
                                              ]
                               )
                          )
        data = [trace1,trace2]
        fig  = go.Figure(data = data,layout = layout)
        py.iplot(fig)
```

Any advice?

Comment: Could you provide a complete snippet with imports and a data sample?